# Which is the right package in the yum repo for Ops Agent on RHEL7?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yum, rhel, repo

I am trying to install the Ops Agent from the GCP yum repo: https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/

I see there are 4 different packages for this agent:

```
google-cloud-ops-agent-el7-x86_64-0
google-cloud-ops-agent-el7-x86_64-1
google-cloud-ops-agent-el7-x86_64-2
google-cloud-ops-agent-el7-x86_64-all
```

What is the difference between the suffixes, -0, -1, -2, and -all? I've tried looking through the docs but couldn't find anything, and I am confused over which one I should get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In easy words to say, those suffixes inform which versions this package contains. 1 contains all versions 1.X.X, 2 contains 1.X.X and 2.X.X, 3 would contain 1.X.X, 2.X.X and 3.X.X. Suffix `All` contains all previous versions.

For example [google-cloud-ops-agent-el7-x86_64-0](https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/google-cloud-ops-agent-el7-x86_64-0/repodata/other.xml) you will see that it's like general version, without any packages:

```
<otherdata xmlns="http://linux.duke.edu/metadata/other" packages="0"> </otherdata>
```

If you will go to to [google-cloud-ops-agent-el7-x86_64-1](https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/google-cloud-ops-agent-el7-x86_64-1/repodata/other.xml), you can find that this contains all packages in version 1.X.X

```
<otherdata xmlns="http://linux.duke.edu/metadata/other" packages="11">
<package pkgid="9e1911332c4bb281655f43337b1366eb52211e425632790552e3826601b60c65" name="google-cloud-ops-agent" arch="x86_64">
<version epoch="0" ver="1.0.0" rel="1.el7"/>
</package>
<package pkgid="df21da80081071f988ad8dae5132ccadec9018253e309ad4d41604e1b0d1867f" name="google-cloud-ops-agent" arch="x86_64">
<version epoch="0" ver="1.0.1" rel="1.el7"/>
</package>
```

In [google-cloud-ops-agent-el7-x86_64-2](https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/google-cloud-ops-agent-el7-x86_64-2/repodata/other.xml) you will have 30, which contains versions `1.X.X` and `2.X.X`.

```
<otherdata xmlns="http://linux.duke.edu/metadata/other" packages="30">
<package pkgid="9e1911332c4bb281655f43337b1366eb52211e425632790552e3826601b60c65" name="google-cloud-ops-agent" arch="x86_64">
<version epoch="0" ver="1.0.0" rel="1.el7"/>
</package>
...
<package pkgid="a5657f70a86d4bf49421d4398417f201719ddfc036d592c1dc108764529909ab" name="google-cloud-ops-agent" arch="x86_64">
<version epoch="0" ver="2.0.3" rel="1.el7"/>
</package>
```

Some additional information you can find in [here](https://semver.org/).

If you are not blocked by some specific version dependencies you can use `google-cloud-ops-agent-el7-x86_64-all` or `google-cloud-ops-agent-el7-x86_64-2` as from first sight, they contains the same packages.

**HOWEVER**, if you want to deploy `OPS Agent` on `GCP`, there is already a guide - [Installing the Ops Agent](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent/install-index)

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for the really detailed response, it has indeed helped me progress with my project and offered a better understanding of what all those packages are and how they work. Thank you for the help on this one!